# Javascript Select Box Style Example (no Javascript framework dependency)

Tags: javascript

I really like projects like this: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ but they use jQuery, which is not an option for the project I am on. I just need a regular Javascript example that styles select boxes but I cannot find any. Does anyone know of one that does not have a dependency on a Javascript framework?

Edit: Since someone thinks they should close this question, how about this instead: could you provide an example of how one would use Javascript to mimic a select box with html/css and still get the form value from a select box?

Comment: As far as I'm aware jquery is not a framework, is a JavaScript library which solves a lot of the cross browser issues and add fx and lot more functionality.

Comment: @FedericoGiust My only concern is using an example that doesn't require another dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is in HTML5, you could use the `<datalist>` element which basically does the same thing as the jQuery chosen plugin ([the datalist element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-datalist-element.html#the-datalist-element) in the HTML5 specification).

The problem is that it is far from being implemented in all modern browsers yet and there’s no polyfill I’m aware of that do not rely on jQuery (but you can always make it degrades gracefully using this [fallback solution](http://adactio.com/journal/4272/)).

Comment: I'll take a look at the datalist. It's definitely hard to find examples that don't use jQuery or something else.

Comment: Apparently [there are plans](https://github.com/chriscoyier/Relevant-Dropdowns#todo) to remove Modernizr and jQuery dependancies for the Relevant-Dropdowns polyfill.

Comment: Looks like they forgot about the issue. I'll try to revive it :) Thanks for finding that :)